# Why an object, created in client side, is not accessible from server side in GWT development mode?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt

I am running my GWT application in development mode. In my client side code (Classes that implements Entrypoint), I have created one object and assigned it to a static variable of another class (Suppose Class A).

Now, expectedly I can access the object by he reference of the static variable of class A from anywhere from the client side but can't access it from the server side code. Can anybody explain me why I can't access the object the same way I accessed it from client side code as **both the client and server running within the same session scope on the same JVM** in development mode.

Comment: what scope has the static variable?

Comment: What are you doing? mixing client and server side code. creating a tight coupling between layers. how come is it possible to read a value directly that resides at client browser?

Comment: I haven't put the object under any scope (eg: session or application) as it is created at client side. According to my understanding, as I have assigned the object to a static variable, hence it is accessible across the client side by the reference of the classname.staticvariable.

Comment: Yes it is accessible at client side only.

Answer (score 3):

Your client side code and server are not running inside one JVM, even in a dev mode. As you know, GWT client code is compiled into Javascript code. So updating some static field is eventually compiled into updating some property of Javascript object. In can not be accessed by Server side code for obvious reasons.

Dev mode in GWT is smart enough and not allows to mix Server and Client static variables to avoid confusion after deploying compiled version to your server.

Comment: According to http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html - In development mode Java Virtual Machine (JVM) actually executes the application code as compiled Java bytecode. Development mode uses a special engine to run our app as a mix of both Java bytecode and native JavaScript, which hence enables debugging facilities of our IDE. Anyway Request you to clarify how GWT Dev mode maintains the barrier in heap space(where the object has been created) between the client and the server as they are running on the same JVM.

Comment: Yes, there is a bytecode of client code for debugging purposes. I haven't checked GWT dev mode internals, however I think that they simply use different class loaders for server and client classes. It would give different values for static variables. We don't need any "heap space barriers" for that.

Answer (score 0):

> You can not access client side classes directly from server side classes and vice versa.

If you want to share some thing between client and server then use shared package but still its for specific purpose such as constants, validators, utilities, DTO (Data Transfer Object) etc.

Do not use any GWT UI specific code in shared classes. Shared package is also visible to server and there is no meaning of your customized widgets.

Read here about [GWT MVP atchitecture](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html)

Read more here about [GWT Architectural Perspectives](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.doc.DeveloperGuide.RemoteProcedureCalls.ArchitecturalPerspectives.html)

---

Create your objects in shared package to communicate between client and server.

One more thing any changes made at client side will not reflect at server side whether it is stored in shared classes or not. You have to pass the value to the server via GWT RPC calls.

Comment: I understand that it is not a good practice to mix client-server code. But only out of curiosity I want to know why I am not able to access the object by using the static variable from both client and server when they are running on the same JVM. Can you please give some insight on how GWT separates the heap space for client and server code in dev mode.

Comment: You are building a web application. Think in that perspective. Your application will never run in dev mode at all.

Comment: Client side code is compiled in JavaScript. Seriously I don't know how GWT internally handle it but I know one think how my application will work in production mode.