# Consolidation of shared and client package

Tags: gwt

I just played around with the GWT sample project generated by Eclipse and realized that you can move all classes from client package to shared and it works as before. I'd like to use a *package by feature* strategy rather than *package by layer* for my project. My idea is to put a domain class with its UI class in one package inside shared.

Are there any side effects or cons for this approach?

Comment: In my experience domain classes are often used by multiple "features". For example, a Customer class might be used in the "shopping cart" feature and in the "sales analysis" feature. I wouldn't restrict domain classes to specific features.

Comment: Terminology nit-pick: client/shared/server isn't quite 'package by layer', but 'package by compatibility'. In theory, any class in shared can be run in the browser or the JVM, but this is not true for classes in client or server. Attempting to run client classes on the server will result in link errors, attempting to run server classes on the client will result in compiler errors.

Comment: @Andy The domain classes would still be public and usable by different features.

Comment: I'll try package by feature and see if some simple conventions keep it maintainable. If so, i expect to have cleaner and more modular code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no side effects. Use the project structure that suits your needs. Just remember to consider longer-term code maintenance, especially if other developers may take over your code later.

Answer (score 0):

As per GWT project structure *Shared* package is used to share the classes that is used both *Client* and *Server* side as well.

Now you don't want to expose the presentation logic to the server, if you did then still there will be no point of it.

Mostly Data Transfer Object, POJO and Utility classes comes under Shared package. I have already posted it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893015/why-an-object-created-in-client-side-is-not-accessible-from-server-side-in-gwt/22893544#22893544) that will help you to understand it better.

Read more

- [GWT MVP atchitecture](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html)
- [GWT Architectural Perspectives](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.doc.DeveloperGuide.RemoteProcedureCalls.ArchitecturalPerspectives.html)

---

### Side effect:

You are mixing different layers of the web application. You are moving away from [Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern and trying to reproduce the same problem that's why this design pattern is discovered by experts after a lots of experience.

It's worth reading [What Are The Benefits of MVC? – the Gang of Four](http://blog.iandavis.com/2008/12/09/what-are-the-benefits-of-mvc/)

Comment: GWT's presentation logic is exposed to the server during development time anyway. 

So you just have to know to not use classes from the client package. 
With my approach you would have to know that a certain ui class from each feature package should not be accessed.
I think that would be quite easy because the server simply does not deal with presentation.

The separation of concerns would be more on class level instead of package level. And i don't think it is a violation of MVC. You would just have your MVC mechanism in one package instead of many.

Comment: I want to build a system where packages are plugins, that you can drop in and out.
Beside this, package by feature has many advantages: [link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205)

Comment: OK fine then go ahead. There will no issue to consolidate only shared and client package.